# How to run a .net core application locally that passes through VPN

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, networking

From my local machine, I am trying to connect to a third party developer portal , where they only allow a whitelist of IP addresses into the portal. I have a VPN on my machine, and if I call out using Postman or Powershell, it calls out through the VPN where we have configured to NAT to a whitelisted IP for the URL specified) and the API calls work. See here for example:

```
$url = "https://some_host/some_path"
$headers = @{
   'Api-Key' = '612345'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers $headers -Uri $url -ContentType $contentType
```

However, when I run a .NET Core web application via Visual Studio locally on my machine, and call out to the same URL with the same headers etc, I get a 403 forbidden (IP address not allowed) error.

In my Program.cs I have the following code:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           })
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
           {
               var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;

               config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                   .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
           });
```

Has anyone come across this issue before, and any Ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: The PS example is acting like a client, but your program.cs defines a host app. I do not see the client c# code which results in 403. Or something is missing from the question :)

Comment: Hi bstack, i have the same problem. Have you find a solution for this?